# Pass Table variable from one stored procedure to another?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement where it would be very beneficial to be able to pass a table variable from a calling stored procedure to a called stored procedure. Is the possible or do I have to use a table valued parameter. Very small amount of data being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table variable is scoped at the sproc level.
Option 1)
You can use a temp table.  However, if the sproc can be called by multiple processes. it might not be a good idea.  Unless you finger print the temp table.

Option 2)
If the amount the data you passing is small, use XML string.

Comment: Thanks @SilentChaos - the XML string is the thing :)